# pipfile editable package location

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pipenv

I'm able to have the source files I'm working on installed to an editable package directory following the instructions [here](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/#editable-dependencies-e-g-e).

So my pipenv looks like

```
[dev-packages]
pytest = "*"
my-package= {editable = true, path = "."}
```

This allows me to run

```
pipenv install --dev
```

then

```
pytest
```

to test.

Is it possible to put my package into in `./src`? I've tried that and I'm told the path is invalid.

```
ValueError: Invalid path './src'
```

*After Carlo's answer + the improvement from hoefling 
Here's a project that verified Carlo's answer
https://github.com/ollyjshaw/alan_pytridge/

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger, but you've accepted the wrong answer. Instead of moving the setup script to `src`, making it the new project root, you should map the source root in the setup script correctly. `setup(name="alan_pytridge", packages=find_packages(where='src'), package_dir={'': 'src'})` is already sufficient. Check out the docs for detailed explanation: [Listing whole packages](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages).

Comment: That works too, thanks. I'll read up the link you have provided. https://github.com/ollyjshaw/alan_pytridge/commit/7c7b1b3288fd77683a45de438e6d51704fc63388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able install a path as editable, it needs to be a package and that means you need to have a `setup.py` file in that directory.